# Powerquery- 2 tables, all rows, choose columns to append to and new columns to add

Tags: excel, append, powerquery

i have two tables. Some fields match, some do not. I want to combine them such that the result has the number of rows equal to the sum of rows in table 1 and table 2.

Is there a way to specify which columns to combine from the two tables and which columns to create a new column for? For Access users, it's kind of like the query editor Append Query where the user can select which columns to append a table to.

I guess I can change the headers to match manually (it just occurred to me), is there a more expedient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two tables:

[image]

Say I want to append the columns *Column1* and *Column3* from *Table1* and *Column2* from *Table2*, to get this:

[image]

Here's *one* way to do it.

First, connect both tables *Table1* and *Table2* to Power Query as sources. Once connected as sources, you'll see them listed on the left of your Power Query screen, under Queries.

Then, start a new blank query: Home -> New Source -> Other Sources -> Blank Query, and type `= Table.Combine({Table.FromColumns({Table1[Column1], Table1[Column3]},{"Table1 Column1","Table1 Column3"}), Table.FromColumns({Table2[Column2]}, {"Table2 Column2"})})`into the formula bar. Then enter.

To learn about the functions I used, see Microsoft's info on [Table.FromColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260759.aspx) and [Table.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260748.aspx). Basically, this code creates two tables...one from *Table1 Column1* and *Table1 Column3*, and one from *Table2 Column2*...then it combines (appends) those two freshly created tables together.